# ORACLE: Trigger with time periods

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables:

-CONTRACTS(manager,start_date,end_date,cat_num)

-TEAMS(manager,start_date,end_date)

I want to check with a trigger if all managers have a cat_num between 4 and 9 in CONTRACTS when they appear on TEAMS.

That's my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER T1
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF manager on teams
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  nJP NUMBER;
  project_enddate DATE;
BEGIN
  SELECT sysdate INTO project_enddate FROM projects WHERE :NEW.end_date IS NULL;
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO nJP
    FROM CONTRACTS c
    WHERE c.manager = :NEW.manager AND ((:NEW.start_date<c.start_date AND project_enddate>c.start_date) OR (:NEW.start_date>c.start_date)) AND c.cat_num BETWEEN 4 AND 9;
  IF nJP = 0 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'Error: INVALID CAT_NUM');
  END IF;
END T1;
/
```

I check all rows in Contracts which time period is contained on my insertion dates.

I use *project_enddate* because end_date in projects could be NULL, and I change the value to sysdate (maybe here can be the error) (just below of begin).

When I insert a correct row, my trigger shows me an error during execution and I dont know why. Here a example:

```
TABLE CONTRACTS
MANAGER         START_DA END_DATE    CAT_NUM
--------------- -------- -------- ----------
12345           01/10/96 30/09/99          9
12345           01/10/99 30/09/01          8
12345           01/10/01 14/10/04          7
12345           01/02/11 31/01/14          6
12345           01/02/14                   6
```

When I insert into teams values ('12345',to_date('05/02/15','DD-MM-YY'),to_date('29/03/16','DD-MM-YY'))

appears execution error of my trigger:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.DISP_CAT_SUP", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.DISP_CAT_SUP'
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be helpful to tell us what the error is??

Comment: Replace "SELECT sysdate INTO project_enddate FROM projects WHERE :NEW.end_date IS NULL;" with "IF :NEW.end_date IS NULL THEN project_enddate := SYSDATE; END IF". If projects tables has > 1 row your SELECT will error

Comment: @OldProgrammer I suspect it's ORA-01422

Comment: Is this `SYSTEM.DISP_CAT_SUP` a procedure? The error seems not to be related with your specific trigger. Can you check if there are any other triggers associated to this table `teams` ?

Comment: Thanks all!!! I fix my problem with TenG comment :D